# EWS and Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices

Reading the documentation, I am a little confused. I have an on premises Exchange 2016 Server. Will I be able to use Microsoft Graph? All the documentation that I am reading is for Exchange Live or outlook 365 using Azure.. I thought Outlook 365 was the cloud version of outlook 2016.

I know I can use EWS but I have read that it will be decommissioned in 2020.

http://techgenix.com/ews-no-updates/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first question, if you have an hybrid deployment of Exchange, you could use the graph api. See [docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/hybrid_rest_support) and a [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/deva/2017/07/22/use-microsoft-graph-api-to-reach-on-premises-cloud-users-of-hybrid-exchange-2016/) but you'll have to go through some extra configurations.

Microsoft changed the blog item announcing this change. There is now extra empathize on the **This change is only for the Office 365 version**.

Original blog item https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2018/07/03/upcoming-changes-to-exchange-web-services-ews-api-for-office-365/

Apart from that, it is just one method of authentication. You can still use other methods.